# Redirect URI on NGINX

Tags: nginx

I have a page on my site (only accessible to logged in users), that looks like the following:

https://www.example.com/forum/new

However, sometimes when users click or refresh they get the page as follows:

https://www.example.com/forum%252fnew

Now %25 decodes to the % symbol, and %2f decodes to the "/", so it seems the URI is getting double-encoded.

I'm not sure how this encoding is happening, but I thought a workaround would be to have Nginx redirect back to the correct URL, with something like the following:

```
location ~ /forum%252Fnew {
    return 301 https://www.example.com/forum/new;
}
```

I have tried escaping the % in the location with \, but neither seem to be working.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URI has been decoded and normalized before being processed by the `location` and `rewrite` directives, so the `%25` looks like a single `%`.

The example in your question shows a *regular expression* `location` statement. The `~` operator is for case-dependent matching, whereas the `~*` operator is for case-independent matching.

To make the example in your question work, you will need to change it to:

```
location ~* /forum%2Fnew
```

Or:

```
location ~ /forum%2fnew
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: Thank you. Seems the problem was the double-encoding, so the single encoded redirect seems to be the solution.